# How to read updated data from a file using the same old file handle

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
open filehandle, "<temp.txt";
@opt=<filehandle>;

    open file, ">temp.txt";
    print file "a\n";
    print file "b\n";
    print file "c\n";
    print file "y\n";
    print file "x\n";
    print file "d\n";
    close $file;
seek filehandle, 0,0;
@a=<filehandle>;
foreach $f (@a){
#while (<filehandle>) {
    print ;
}
close filehandle;
```

I have some data in a file that I'm opening in read mode. Later, I'm updating data by opening in write mode and then closing the file handle of write mode.

Now I want to read the updated data using the same old file handle without reopening the file. Is there any possibility to do it?

The above code is not reading the updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track... The main issue is that you opened `file`, a bareword, but closed `$file`, a variable.

However, you should really stop using bareword file handles as they are global to other perl processes, and also may clash with future functions, or functions from another module. Instead, use lexical (`my`) variables for file handles. I'd recommend starting your scripts with `use strict` to enforce (among other things) all variables are properly declared and scoped. It's also recommended you add `use warnings` to catch more errors in your script.

Here is a more correct way of doing what you want

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'temp.txt';

open my $fh_read, '<', $filename;
my @input = <$fh_read>;

open my $fh_write, '>', $filename;
print {$fh_write} "new data goes here\n";
close $fh_write;

seek $fh_read, 0, 0;
my @new_input = <$fh_read>;
print for @new_input;
```

Comment: It is giving error  "Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at D:\coding\new.pl line 56.
Execution of D:\coding\new.pl aborted due to compilation errors."

Comment: Fixed. `$file` was the var holding the filename but I accidentely deleted it. I've changed the var name to `$filename` to be more explicit. Any time you refer to a literal name more than once (like 'temp.txt') it's best to put it in a variable so you don't need to repeat yourself.

Comment: Should always catch errors on open: `open my $ fh,  '<', $filename or die $!;`

Comment: Also, it's a lot more memory efficient to loop over the fIle a line at a time instead of slurping the whole thing into an array where possible (it most often is): `while (<$fh>){ print; }`

Comment: stevieb: is certainly not how I'd write the script, just modernised op's script.

Comment: If it's not how you would write the script, why did you post it? And why would you go to the trouble of teaching them about strict, warnings, lexical filehandles, and 3-arg `open`, but stop short of teaching them to check the success of `open`?